# Searching for record(s) in a table that has over 200 Million Rows

Tags: sql

Which type of index should be used on the table? It is initially inserted (one a month) into a empty table. I then place a non clustered composite index on two of the columns. Wondering if merging the two fields into one would increase performance when searching. Or does it not matter? Should I be working with an identity column that has a primary key clustered index?

Answer (score 0):

You should index the field(s) most likely to be used in the where clause as people query the table.  Don't worry about the primary key - it already has an index.

Answer (score 0):

If you can define a unique primary key that can be used when querying the table, this will be used as the clustered index and will be the fastest for selects.

If your select query has to use the two fields you mentioned, keep them separate. Performance will not be impacted and the schema is not spoiled.

Answer (score 0):

*"A clustered index is particularly efficient on columns that are often searched for ranges of values. After the row with the first value is found using the clustered index, rows with subsequent indexed values are guaranteed to be physically adjacent."*

With this in mind you probably won't see much benefit from haveing a clustered index on your primary key (ID) unless it have business meaning for your aplication. If you have a Date value that you are commonly querying, then it may make more sense to add a clustered index to that

```
select * from table where created > '2013-01-01' and created < '2013-02-01'
```

I have seen datawarehouses use a concatenated key approach. Whether this works for you depends on your queries. Obviously querying a single field value will be faster than multiple fields, particularly when there is one less lookup in the B-tree index.

Alternatively, if you have 200 million rows in a table you could look at breaking the data out into multiple tables if it makes sense to do so.

You're saying that you're loading all this data every month so I have to assume that all the data is relevant. If there was data in your table that is considered "old" and not relevant to searches, then you could move data out into a archive table (using the same schema) so your queries only run against "current" data.

Otherwise, you can look at a *sharding* approach as used by NoSQL like  MongoDB. If MongoDB is not an option, you could achieve the same shard key like logic in your application. I doubt that your database SQL drivers will support sharding natively.